# Как изменить значения элементов управления документа Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Есть шаблон документа Word с несколькими полями с простым текстом. Нужно программно сохранить в эти поля значения. Вроде бы все просто, но при попытке это сделать возникает исключение "Нет такого параметра". Что я делаю не так?

```
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref templateFileName, ref newTemplate, ref documentType, ref visible);
Debug.WriteLine(wordDoc.ContentControls.Count);
var controls = wordDoc.ContentControls;
foreach (Word.ContentControl control in controls)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(control.Title);

}
wordDoc.ContentControls["caCode"].Range.Text = "тест";
```

Исключение возникает на последней строке кода.

При этом предыдущие строки корректно выводят количество (5) и названия элементов управления (caCode, caDate и т. д.).

Comment: ИМХО, упоминание WPF в вопросе излишне, так как конкретно по нему тут ничего в вопросе нет.

Comment: Здесь написано что надо передавать индекс, а не строку: [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.contentcontrols.item?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_ContentControls_Item_System_Object__)

Comment: попробуйте с помощью Linq: `var cc = controls.Single(c => c.Title == "caCode"); cc.Range.Text = "тест";`

Comment: Компилятор ругается:
Ошибка CS1061 "ContentControls" не содержит определения для "Single", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Single", принимающий тип "ContentControls" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Comment: Пространство имён подключите: `System.Linq`

Comment: Подключено, не влияет: using System.Linq; Может быть нужно ещё какое-нибудь пространство имен из Microsoft.Office? У меня подключено только это: using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; Или может быть .NET Framework другой версии? У меня стоит 4.6.1 в настройках проекта

Comment: Если написано `wordDoc.ContentControls["caCode"].Range.Text` то у вас как минимум два теста должно быть на null. `ContentControls["caCode"]` - чему равно? А Range чему равно?

Comment: Строка Debug.WriteLine(ContentControls["caCode"]); вызывает исключение: Необработанное исключение типа "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" в OperationalWarehouse.exe
Неверный параметр.

Comment: Debug.WriteLine(wordDoc.ContentControls["caCode"]); точнее вот такая строка, пропустил одно слово

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался сам. Помог разобраться пример макроса на VBA.
Получение контролов напрямую не работает, но работает через вызов метода объекта Document MS Word SelectContentControlByTitle(). При этом возвращается не один контрол, а коллекция из которой затем извлекается сам контрол. Вот такой код работает корректно:

```
    ContentControls controls = wordDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("caCode");
    ContentControl control = controls[1];
    control.Range.Text = "тест";
```